# ActiveMQ Artemis - cannot see message or message counts in console, queues tab, although they have not yet been consumed

Tags: user-interface, console, mqtt, activemq-artemis

How can you see data accumulating in the ActiveMQ queues on the console? I have about 20-30 messages in ActiveMQ waiting for the Telegraph Listener to be activated.

However, when I look in the queues I don't see any numbers indicating there are messages in the queue. It's all zeros or ones. Despite that fact the actual functionality of durable message delivery is working.

Below is an image of what I see in the UI:
[image: queued messages not visible]

How do I view message counts/messages?

Comment: How do you know you have 20-30 messages waiting to be consumed if the message count indicates there are 0 messages? According to the screenshot all the InfluxData queues have consumers on them already which means the messages are being consumed as they arrive. By default the console only refreshes every 5 seconds which means you may not be seeing the messages before they get consumed. You should look at the view for the specific queue you're interested in and it will tell you how many messages have been added & consumed as well as how many are in delivery.

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram  - this was user error! The telegraf listener was consuming the messages and waiting for the influx database to come up. When I turned off the Telegeraf consumer, I could see the messages. 

Thanks!

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I put my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screenshot all the InfluxData queues have consumers on them already which means the messages are almost certainly being consumed as they arrive. By default the console only refreshes every 5 seconds which means you may not be seeing the messages before they get consumed.

You should look at the view for the specific queue you're interested in and it will tell you how many messages have been added & consumed as well as how many are in delivery.